# Game statistics: Extracting interesting patterns out of users and level

Tags: statistics, recreational-mathematics, pattern-recognition

I made a small game and in course of time collected fair amount of data between users and level

The level chart is long (120 levels) but looks somewhat like this

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\text{level} & \text{No. of Users}\\\hline
5 & 20\\
6 & 23\\
7 & 15\\
10 & 2\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Being a math nitwit I don’t know how to extract useful information out of this. Can someone help me with this so that I can learn more about my users and give them things they want?

Comment: What exactly is your question? I think you need to figure out (or tell us) what "useful information" you want. Perhaps try gamedev.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Are there more attributes? As it stands, (Level, Number) doesn't seem very informative.

Answer (score 2):

The data isn't hugely rich, so there's only a certain amount of insight you can get. If you had more data (eg, number of attempts at each level, time spent on each level).

In your position, the main question I would be trying to answer is: **Which levels cause an unusual number of players to stop playing?** I suspect that simply plotting the data you have onto a chart would help you spot the answer without any further calculations.

I would do this by calculating the users lost for each level:

```
UsersLost(level) = Users(level - 1) - Users(level)
```

(Depending on the shape of the data, you may find it more useful to model the proportion of users lost, rather than the absolute number.)

I would look at the distribution of these numbers to help me determine the next information I was interested in. Again, plotting the results is a useful exploratory tool.

Ultimately, I'd be looking for any levels where there's a big difference between the *expected* number of users lost and the *actual* number of users lost. These are the levels you want to investigate closely, to help identify the qualitative reason that they lose/keep users.

At this stage, I think that you'd be better off asking on a forum more suited to exploratory analytics and the user experience -- someone suggested [gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) as a good starting point. Mathematics might be more useful when you have figured out what you're looking for (and need help finding it).

Comment: Your expression for `UsersLost` will be negative for level 6 - what might this mean?

Comment: It means there is a way for a user to count on level 6 without counting on level 5. Perhaps the game has a "skip level" facility? The general principles I outline should still apply as long as players progress somewhat linearly through the levels.